# how to color my code in octopress blog page

Tags: github, github-pages, octopress

I am new to octopress, and I wrote some blog there and put it into my jaskey.github.io.It is cool but I found that my code is not colored as what stackoverflow does.

Now I use spacespacespacespace to begin with my code block, which does not color my code.

And then I tried writing my code after  `java (enter)  {code here.....}enter`java,  and this makes my blog become a blank page!

Is it any easy way to make my code looks more cool(I am using windows 7)?

ps:here is how I write my post:
I use command rake new_post["title"] to create an markdown page,and then I write in markdown pad, and then rake generate, rake deploy.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a repository ? It's easiest to spot problems with code to read.

Comment: @DavidJacquel , yeah, jaskey.github.io. But it is written in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at these references:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code

https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code

Those are Markdown references.

In line code should have backtick quotes, not regular single quotes. `This is a backtick`. While 'this is not'.

To use a paragraph of code you should enclose it with 3 backticks

`These are 3 backticks
another line
another`

```If you start with 3 backticks and don't put them at the end

of the paragraph, this is what happens

Keep in mind that syntax highlighting is not part of Markdown specifications (as far as I know).

Do you want to color the code in your terminal or in your live blog?

If you want it on your terminal, you can do this with Textmate or Sublime. You could also do it with Tmux and Vim.

To color your code on your website you could try this: https://highlightjs.org/ (HighlightJS)

Comment: how can I use higntlightjs into my github page?

Answer (score 0):

By reading Octopress [documentation](http://octopress.org/docs/blogging/code/) and code, you can see that they are doing syntax highlighting with plugins. And plugins don't work on github pages.

If you want gh pages to generate your site, the only way to go it to use **[Jekyll highlight tag](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#highlighting-code-snippets)**.

If you want to use Octopress highlight plugins, you will have to generate your site locally and then [deploy to gh pages](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/).

Comment: May I know how to let my github page works with Jekyll highlight tag? May I have a quick start on the answer or a guide for this?

Comment: Link to [Jekyll highlight tag](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#highlighting-code-snippets) was in my answer.